# Magento Custom Report remove column

Tags: magento

How do i remove the Period column from my custom report?

i tried with 
   **`unset($this->_columns['period']);`**
but its not working.

I need to start my columns like order number, order date,subtotal etc etc.

[image: Current Output]

[image: Output Required]

Answer (score 1):

This is loaded by a custom grid of Backend of Magento, you need identify this. To find the custom block you can active backend hints and see what grid are loaded in this section.

You can active backend hints with the next Sql:

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET scope_id = 0 WHERE path like 'dev/debug/template_hints%';
```

Execute always in development enviroment. Never in production site

You can see how to active backend hints in this link, `http://www.damianculotta.com.ar/2009/07/11/mostrar-phtmls-y-bloques-usados-en-el-skin-de-backend-de-magento/` sorry, this is in spanish, I don´t find this information in english :(

With this you also to know the type of block load in this grid, this is the important date. Next you need create a little module that rewrite this block.

Whit this method you can see that the next dates

```
Template
adminhtml\default\default\template\widget/grid.phtml

Block
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Sales_Sales_Grid
```

in the block you can see the next columm in the construct

```
 $this->addColumn('period', array(
        'header'        => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Period'),
        'index'         => 'period',
        'width'         => 100,
        'sortable'      => false,
        'period_type'   => $this->getPeriodType(),
        'renderer'      => 'adminhtml/report_sales_grid_column_renderer_date',
        'totals_label'  => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Total'),
        'html_decorators' => array('nobr'),
    ));
```

You need remove this columm in you custom block, always in separate extension.
If you don´t know how you can rewrite a block, only need said me :P
Hope help you

Comment: I have copied and paste a customer total grid as per my requirement and used the block like class My_Customreport_Block_Adminhtml_Customreport_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Grid {


as similar to 


class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Customer_Totals_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Grid

and i dont find any columns for "Period" similar to what is in
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Sales_Sales_Grid
as it is extending Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Grid_Abstract

Do you have any idea how can i get this out from the grid similar to Customer by Orders Total report ?.

Thanks

Comment: You need to know the block load in this part of the backend and if you don´t find the addcolum, you should search in the class structures to find it. Are you sure is the Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Customer_Totals_Grid loaded in this location????

Comment: i said i have used the similar structure used in the default magento for "Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Customer_Totals_Grid".

Comment: Any help on this, for the partial solution i have remove the <th> and <td> from the grid.phtml but i know this is not the exact solution.
I need to remove the period column from report as well.